# After I burn the image file to the sd card, it cannot work on the Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspberrypi, sd-card

[image: The photo is after inserting the SD card and power supply in the burning system]I follow the tutorial to burn the image file to the SD card, insert the SD card into the Raspberry Pi and plug in the power, but the Raspberry Pi cannot start（I download at http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-core/18/stable/current/ubuntu-core-18-armhf+raspi.img.xz ；Unzip with Bandizip；burn with Win32DiskImager； and use Raspberry Pi 4B）
Who can help me!!!

Comment: Did you extract the content from the xz-compression before you cloned it with Win32DiskImager? You can install and use [7-zip](https://www.7-zip.org/download.html) to extract the content. See also [**this link**](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Win32DiskImager/compressed-image_2_USB-or-SD).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I followed the tutorial every step of the way. The raspios system that was originally burned to the SD card can be used normally, but after resetting the SD card and re-burning the ubuntu system, it does not work.

Comment: There is a message in the screenshot: 'This board requires newer software ..." So either get it from the suggested web site, or try the [newest Ubuntu 'arm64+raspi' or 'armhf+raspi' version](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/20.04.1/release/).

Comment: Thank you very much. Please forgive me for my bad English.

Comment: Please share your results here (good or bad). I hope you succeed now, otherwise I or someone else can help you with the next step :-)

Answer (score -1):

I've got the same problem same boot screen, i've tried to install the latest image ( https://ubuntu.com/download/raspberry-pi-core ) on my 32GB card with Raspberri Pi Imager, Balena Etcher and the official ubuntu instruction and got the same result : no boot. The only Ubuntu i've sucessfully boot on my new Raspberri Pi 4 is Ubuntu server 20 with Imager. i've also tried to modify the conf file as specified here (https://jamesachambers.com/raspberry-pi-ubuntu-server-18-04-2-installation-guide/ ) without any result.